# Optimizing string parsing in core java

Tags: java, string, split

In case we have a situation to parse the string using split method. Now, if there are millions of the string to be parsed then we have lot of string in memory. Although, logically we can store the commonly parsing string in a separate map and return already parsed string. This leads to have, additionally, Map, in worse case, the Map will be as many as million entries.

Is there any way to have optimum solution so that we can save the memory and parse the string as well.

Answer (score 3):

The parsed strings will be discarded when the array created out of `String.split()` is eligible for garbage collection. You could try interning them manually by calling `String.intern()` but this could lead to String Pool growing to an unreasonable size if there are millions of unique strings that are used rarely.

Instead I'd suggest to switch to G1GC. On JRE 8u20 or newer you can use the string deduplication feature ([JEP 192: String Deduplication in G1](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/192)) by setting:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:+PrintStringDeduplicationStatistics
```

`PrintStringDeduplicationStatistics` should output statistics that will tell you if string deduplication is taking place.

Comment: I am just thinking, if String being immutable. Can we have some other technique to handle this kind of issues outside of Java. A caching technique outside of Java can be useful, but the catch is how efficient, secure and trustworthy? Most of the memory is occupied by char[], thus either in future should provide this issue resolved or external caching mechanism is good enough for now?

Comment: Memory, CPU cycles, and other hardware is generally cheap comparing to software development cost. You can come up with your own perfect solution for your specific use-case but if similar performance can be achieved with 1 GB extra heap and few JVM flags I don't think it would be worth it to pursue it (other than for learning something new).